# Counting clicks in web - best way?

Tags: php, count

I already wrote a program in PHP increasing the value in a text file, but I have been told this can go bad when mulitple users are using the same PHP script at the same time.

Dose anyone know how to fix this problem or a better way? All I need is to count the clicks of a button and save them in a way and show it in another page.

This is my code:

```
<?php

    $clicks = file_get_contents("clicks.txt");
    $clicks++;

        $fp = fopen("clicks.txt", "w+");
        fwrite($fp, $clicks);
        fclose($fp);

//give the count to the user
echo "result: $clicks";

    ?>
```

Comment: You can use a database with a database lock to make sure that only one script is adjusting the value at a time and other scripts will have to wait for the lock to be released before getting their turn to do the same

Comment: It's not an issue, as long as you use `fopen` with `r+` as a mode. The issues happen when you read and write separately. (This'll be faster than a database, but in real-world applications, you don't often see flat files being used to store any data that will be changed concurrently.)

Comment: No, you're using `file_get_contents` to read it. The contents can change between then and your `fopen`.

Comment: Ok, but how dose this solve my problem of multiple people accesing my site and using the same click script?

Comment: @user1431627 - it doesn't, which is why you have to 'lock' either the file or the database record before manipulating it (reading AND writing)

Comment: Well, but how dose sites like YouTube keep track of their views?

Comment: @minitech - 'r+' only gives you a read/write permission and places the pointer to the beginning of the file, but it doesn't actually stop another thread of the same script from reading the file too, so you can have several threads reading the same value and then writing the same value back multiple times, but this wouldn't give you an accurate number.

Comment: What would you recommend me doing to keep track of my clicks?

Comment: @techexpert: I know what it does. I didn't bother answering with it because sachleen already did.

Answer (score 0):

The reason it can go bad is when two things try to write to the file at the same time. You can avoid this by getting a lock on the file before writing to it. PHP has [`flock`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.flock.php).

Getting an exclusive lock `LOCK_EX` will allow you to write to the file but nobody else. So if you do this, only one instance of your script can write to it at any time. If the script can't get the lock, it means something else is writing to the file so you can try it again or throw an error.

Example from PHP docs on `flock`:

```
$fp = fopen("/tmp/lock.txt", "r+");

if (flock($fp, LOCK_EX)) {  // acquire an exclusive lock
    ftruncate($fp, 0);      // truncate file
    fwrite($fp, "Write something here\n");
    fflush($fp);            // flush output before releasing the lock
    flock($fp, LOCK_UN);    // release the lock
} else {
    echo "Couldn't get the lock!";
}

fclose($fp);
```

For any real world application of this, you'll use a database and insert a row for every click you want to monitor. You can store more information about each click too, like time, what page the person was on, and anything else you may want. Then you can query the database and get all these stats. You'll avoid this issue altogether.

Update: Read [this page](http://www.tuxradar.com/practicalphp/8/11/0) for a tutorial.

Comment: I can't do this :( There must be a way... how dose YouTube track views?

Comment: @user1431627: YouTube uses a database.

Comment: you forgot to do the fread() inside the if(flock...) statement so you can get the most current value in the file before incrementing and writing back to the file

Comment: @techexpert I just copied the example from the PHP page. This was to show how to use `flock`, not copy-paste code to be used.

Comment: The problem is that I MUST track EVERYONE or this would just be unnessesary :)

Comment: `flock` will by default block until it gets the lock on the handle. So it'll just wait until other processes are done and then execute the code.

Comment: @user1431627 read [this page](http://www.tuxradar.com/practicalphp/8/11/0). The second half shows how when using 2 scripts, the second one waits for the first to finish before doing its thing.

Answer (score 0):

Use a database. Mysql for example can give you ACID guarantee for your database transactions.

Comment: Can you help me write up against one database?

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, the answer to your question about the best way to count clicks is to just use a free google analytics account.

If you insist on doing it yourself, you need to log information about each click into a database, and then turn that data into interesting viewable results.

If you are not willing to do either of these things, then your rate of efficacy drops sharply, in which case the method you are already using is already about the best way, given your narrow scope.

Answer (score -1):

If you do not mind refreshing the page, then just send a form with hidden field and increase a number in database.

If you do not want to refresh the page to save the click, then just fire an AJAX request to the server and again do the same thing - save it do database or file if you prefer.